# Installation of ROS KINETIC in Ubuntu 16.04(Xenial)

Tags: ros

I am trying to install ROS KINETIC on Ubuntu 16.04, but every time after 94% installation it stuck,and gives following error....

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libavcodec-ffmpeg56 libavformat-ffmpeg56 libavutil-ffmpeg54 libglib2.0-0
  libglib2.0-bin libgssapi-krb5-2 libicu55 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3
  libkrb5support0 libssl1.0.0 libswresample-ffmpeg1 libswscale-ffmpeg3
  libtiff5 libxml2
15 upgraded, 700 newly installed, 0 to remove and 246 not upgraded.
Need to get 32.3 MB/449 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2,169 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libvtk6.2 amd64 6.2.0+dfsg1-10build1+debian11.1+osrf1
  Connection failed
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vtk6/libvtk6.2_6.2.0+dfsg1-10build1+debian11.1+osrf1_amd64.deb  Connection failed

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Then when I open terminal I get this message. I have no idea how to solve it.
Because of the error I can't install ROS again.

Comment: Try running `apt-get update -f`

Comment: @sempaiscuba probably meant `sudo apt-get install -f`.